# Laravel 7 Passport with different and multiple Models

Tags: api, authentication, laravel-7, laravel-passport

I am currently developing an API with Laravel 7 and I want to authenticate users coming from different applications with Passport : 3 applications communicate with the API, so 3 different user tables.

It's working fine with the User model provided but when I use my own model, I can't login : it responds "Bad credentials" with the good credentials.

So my question is : Is it possible to use a different model from User provided and also multiple model at the same time for each APP/Client ?

Here is a diagram of the structure I want : [Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqWY5.png)

My App\User :

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable{
use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

....

}
```

Here is my login function :

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string'
    ]);
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Bad credentials'
        ], 401);
    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addHours(1);
    $token->save();
    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
            $tokenResult->token->expires_at
        )->toDateTimeString()
    ]);
}
```

}

My config/auth

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'userstest',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'userstest',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
], 'providers' => [
    'userstest' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I tried to reduce my code and keep only the changes I've made. Is it more clear now or do I need to re-explain my problem ?